# How can this shell script (no bash) display seconds as DDD:HH:MM:SS?

Tags: linux, shell-script, scripting, date

```
#!/bin/sh
INTERVAL=12
TOTAL=3388888
DURSECS=$(($TOTAL * $INTERVAL))
printf "\n$DURSECS seconds.\n"
printf "\nFormatted as DAYS:HOURS:MINUTES:SECONDS - DDD:HH:MM:SS - the total duration will be:\n"
# these do not do it
# TOTALTIMES=$(($DURSECS/(24*60*60), "ddd:hh:mm:ss"))
# printf "$TOTALTIMES"
# just need days here
date -u -d @${DURSECS} +"%T"

printf '\n\nTHE END\n'
```

Comment: You haven't asked a question. What is it precisely that you need help with?

Comment: The gnu version of date has a printf-like format system as well as a few standard output formats.  It would probably make this script a small handful of lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How far would

```
echo $((DURSECS / 86400)):$(date +%T -d@$(( DURSECS % 86400 )))
470:17:17:36
```

get you?

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/sh
INTERVAL=102
TOTAL=86401
DURSECS=$(($TOTAL * $INTERVAL))
printf "\n$DURSECS seconds.\n"
printf "\nFormatted as DAYS:HOURS:MINUTES:SECONDS - DDD:HH:MM:SS - the total duration will be:\n"
ddd=$(($DURSECS / 86400))
printf "$ddd:"
date -u -d @${DURSECS} +"%H:%M:%S"
printf '\n\nTHE END\n'
```

Comment: Is this your answer to your own question?

Comment: Yes, I eventually figured it out, but @RudiC really nailed it.